# a2ps compiling on mac

Tags: c, configuration-files

I am compiling `a2ps` on mac machine, and getting error while running ./configure

```
Checking host system type... configure: error: 
                      can not guess host type; you must specify one
```

Tried different --host options but non working.

Comment: Hove you installed the Xcode command line tools? i.e. have you got a C compiler

Comment: No, I am using gcc "Checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes"

Comment: You needed the command line tools to get a compiler that built gcc.- away looks like you need to update auto tools so they have a correct configure (Using package managers like macports , home-brew or fink makes this much easier)